# Finding the row which represent the input value and use it with Index function

Tags: indexing, match

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpsw8.png)My issue is a sample code selection table. In this table I have 2 column in the right. First column represent lower limit of a range. 2nd column represent upper limit. The top of the table represent inspection  type. When using "Index" function based on a input representing number of lot and type of inspection, I have been facing problem to identify the proper row which represent the sample size range.

As lot number very from the higher limit of the second column, I have to use the formula as "MATCH(B4,F4:F18,1)" but using "1" as "match_type" is selecting the pervious row. But I have to find a formula which will select exact row.